# apply clickhandler from map method on refresh

Tags: reactjs

i want to add a clickhandler method on react component but the method done immediately after refresh
map method

```js
<div id="playGround">
                {str.map((fl) => {
                    return <div className="feild" key={fl.id} onClick={this.clickhandler(fl.id)}>{this.writehandler(fl.type)}</div>
                })}
            </div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

clickhandler

```js
clickhandler = (id)=>{
        console.log(id)
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

result on console
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

Comment: You've already added the `onClick`. It should work. What do want to do?

Comment: What do you mean by " method done immediately after refresh map method"? Can you explain properly? Maybe add some more code to help us understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are calling the clickhandler function straight away. To just declare it, change your onClick as such:

```js
onClick={() => this.clickhandler(fl.id)}
```